# Are there any class diagram generating tools for python source code?

Tags: python, uml

Are there any reverse-egineering UML tools for Python?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/260323/1506477

Answer (score 5):

This looks good: http://www.andypatterns.com/index.php?cID=65

How about this? http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/lumpy.html

Comment: I too would recommend PyNSource from AndyPatterns, as it is the most advanced in terms of code analysis. The GUI is very rough, not very usable IMHO.

Comment: andypatterns link is good. this PyNSource tool giving nice class diagram representation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The AndyPatterns application seems to have gone stale, I downloaded it and it couldn't import some simple python files I tried to feed it.

Answer (score 2):

[pyUML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-pyuml/) may be what you are looking for. Although it is an Eclipse plugin for PyDev.

Answer (score 2):

[Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) can reverse engineer Python code, at least according to the documentation. I've never tried it, so I don't know for certain.