# Automatically Generated Python Code from an UML diagram?

Tags: python, uml

*The question is not the same as [What’s the best way to generate a UML diagram from Python source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260165/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-a-uml-diagram-from-python-source-code), but the other way around.*

[Topcoder UML tool](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=dev&d2=umltool&d3=description) automatically generates code in only Java or C#. Since I need to create [a very depended data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185589/three-dimensional-data-structure-a-problem-in-a-db) at a point, I am hesitant to turn to Java. I want to use Python. So:

1. Is there an UML-like tool that
   automatically generates Python code
   from your diagram?
2. If there is, is it possible to generate it from the Topcoder UML tool?
3. Can you shortly compare the tools?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html) is able to generate python code code from UML diagrams.
It is also able to also perform some reverse engineering, and therefore maintain the two versions (UML and python) synchronized together.

However, I have never used it in that way, except for some small tests just to see it in action. I personally find productivity in Python so high, that even if I am really satisfied with EA, I prefer it just to document the design.

Comment: +1: I use UML for conceptual sketches.  The real code is so easy to write that big, formal, detailed UML isn't helpful.

Comment: EA only works for windows. sorry for it.  I would want to try it on my mac.

Comment: @S.Lott, detailed UML isn't helpful unless the project is very large... then detailed UML saves your skin many times over

Comment: @Mike Pennington: Detailed UML is isomorphic to code.  It's easier to write the code.

Comment: @S.Lott, maps are isomorphic to city topology; amazingly, people continue to buy maps.

Comment: @Mike Pennington: True.  But a really bad analogy.   GPS maps lack a great many details.  For instance, you can't actually into any building.  But detailed UML actually is executable by an interpreter, making it isomorphic to code, and much, much more difficult to create.

Comment: @S.Lott, I edited out GPS upon reflection before I saw your comment; nevertheless, the point is you can write sufficiently-complex class relationships that detailed UML is very useful... likewise in some cities, normal people wouldn't dream of navigating to random locations from memory.  I agree that UML code-generation / round-tripping is often more complicated than building the relationships by hand

Comment: @Mike Pennington:  That is my point.  There's a limit to the value of UML, and code-level detail is past the point of value.

Comment: @S.Lott, what exactly are you calling "code-level detail"?  This is where we may not agree.

Comment: @Mike Pennington: Detailed UML is isomorphic to code.  I think that's what I said.

Comment: @S.Lott, code is not always easier to read than UML.  That's what I said

Comment: @Mike Pennington: I have no idea what you're talking about.  The "big picture" or overview or summary or high-level design is hard to grasp from code.  The code-level details are hard to depict in UML.  They're different things.  Details UML -- at the code level -- is obscure and complex.  UML overviews, however, can act as a visual road map into the code.  For details -- and only details -- UML is obscure and code is clear.  For overviews -- and only overviews -- UML can help.   A blanket statement about "UML" being easier to read makes very little sense.  Why do you keep saying it?

Comment: @S.Lott because you continue to rant and be ambiguous about what *specifically* you mean about detailed UML being hard to read.  For the record, I consider detailed UML to include anything in (for Class diagrams) Chapter 3 of Martin Fowler's book... and sometimes  parts of Chapter 5.  UML Sequence diagrams, and Use cases are rather useful... are we disagreeing?  If not, that's why I asked you several comments ago what you meant by "code-level detail"

Comment: @Mike Pennington:  What words should I use to clarify my point?  Detailed UML is isomorphic to code.  What more could I possibly say?  Please provide some guidance.

Comment: The advantage of UML over code is that a single or few architects can specify ins, outs, and functionality in a rough form from UML.  As th team of developers grows in numbers, UML scaffold generation becomes more beneficial.

Comment: @NullPointer Just FYI, EA is one of the explicitly support packages for CrossOver (the commercial version of Wine). I use EA on Windows, OSX, and Ubuntu with very few problems.

Answer (score 7):

- [PyUML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-pyuml/) - a Python Roundtrip Tool for Eclipse
- [PyIdea](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyidea/): PyNSource UML & Patterns IDE for Python

Comment: Can I get PyUML for Easy Eclipse?

Comment: Can you do reverse engineering with PyUML?

Comment: http://www.philroche.net/archives/python-and-uml/. A nice blog a out some tools in this area.

Answer (score 5):

You can use DIA, and then install dia2code, it will generate from UML to code in python.  I use it in PHP5 and Java.

```
$ sudo apt-get install dia dia2code
```

Comment: And as a bonus there is a portable version of Dia for PartableApps.

Answer (score 3):

The [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/) UML modeller for KDE support Python as an export language.

Answer (score 0):

Some tools:

- [Gaphor](http://gaphor.devjavu.com/)
- [pyUML for Eclipse](http://eclipse-pyuml.sourceforge.net/)
- [pyNSource](http://www.andypatterns.com/index.php?cID=65)

Comment: Does gaphor do Python reverse engineering?  Or is it a UML diagramming tool written in Python/GTK+?

Answer (score 0):

Search with Ubuntu found:

```
$ apt-cache search python uml
boa-constructor - RAD tool for Python and WxWindows application
dia2code - a dia-UML code generator
spe - Stani's Python Editor
```

Quick testing revealed that DIA is the only program, where you can export your UML diagram to Python. I am very suspicious about the quality of DIA because it is less intuitive to use than the Topcoder UML program. Perhaps, the other programs, suggested by other repliers, are better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link-

```
https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/276/330/7400_instantgener.html
```

Select Tools > Code > Instant Generator from the toolbar. In the
        Instant Generator window, select Python as the Language. Fill in the
        Output Path, which is the directory where you want the code to
        generate to. Select the classes to generate code. In the Diagrams
        tab, you can select the diagrams to generate code for classes in the
        selected diagrams. Alternatively, open the Model Elements tab and
        select the classes to generate code.