# What is the best tool to draw out large inheritance pieces of code?

Tags: inheritance, drawing, modeling

I have started doing a code review for someone, and there is a large inheritance model (many layers deep).  After filling up my white board, I realized that I need a tool to draw this out.

What is the best tool (preferably free) to draw this out, so I can visualize what's happening in the code base.  The code is in Python, but I think my question or the solution should be generic.  I don't mind drawing it out by hand as the value for me is the scalability around the visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look for [Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) to generate an UML diagram from the source code (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260165/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-a-uml-diagram-from-python-source-code) Stack Overflow question)

Also, [AutoDia](http://www.aarontrevena.co.uk/opensource/autodia/) and [HappyDoc](http://happydoc.sourceforge.net/) claims that can generate Dia UML diagrams from the Python source

Answer (score 0):

[StarUML is free.](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/)

Works great.  It's my go-to UML program when I need to visualize something.  You can do both class and sequence diagrams with it.  It even includes a nice reverse-engineer feature - but upon further review, it looks like python reverse engineering is not supported.

Even so, it's a good alternative to some of the heavier (non-free) proprietary solutions like Rational Rose.