# Positioning of classes in UML diagram

Tags: python, uml, drawing, graph-drawing, pyreverse

I'm creating a tool for displaying Python project as an UML diagram (+ displaying some code error detection using GUI).

I scan some project using Pyreverse and I have all data I need for drawing UML diagram.
The problem is positioning of the class boxes on the canvas.

For a start, I decided to use already implemented force based algorithm to decide about position of classes, it works quite well here's the result
https://github.com/jvorcak/gpylint/blob/master/screenshots/gpylint.png
and here's the [code](https://github.com/jvorcak/gpylint/blob/master/gpylint/writer.py#L53-58) (Python, but it's easy to understand even for non Python programmers).

There is one proble, it's great for displaying graphs, but if I want to display UML I'd like to have some enhancements, for instance if 2 classes extend one superclass, I'd expect them to be at the same level in the graph like in [graphs generated by dot program](http://umldot.sourceforge.net/demo.gif).

Comment: Do you need the placements to be dynamically adjustable by the user?  If not, can you use graphviz's dot program to do the layout for you (http://www.graphviz.org/)?

Comment: thank you for your response, I've already mentioned that I want to know algorithm of dot program (if not, I'll have to browse it's source code), because I want to draw these objects on canvas and allow users to move with them

Comment: It's probably hard, as most Python programs are done with duck-typing. For some of my programs, I didn't use inheritance for all classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the main enhancement you are missing is transforming your graph to a [layered graph.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing) This is **no easy task, but it's doable**. (the quality of the result may vary by the amount of time and thought invested in the process).

The main idea is to do a some kind of [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the graph to split it into layers, do some arrangements in it and then to draw the graph. (you can find python code to do a real topological sort online ([example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577413-topological-sort/)), but real TS will just produces a long line-like graph, and we want something a little different)

So I'll try to describe an algorithm to transform a given graph into a layered one:

1. Topological sorting doesn't work on graphs with cycles, so if the input graph is not already a directed graph with no cycles, you'll have to find a set of edges that can be removed (or possibly reversed) to create an a cyclic graph (you will later add them to the layered graph, but that will brake the layering and make the graph less pretty :). Since Finding the smallest possible set of edges you can remove is NP-complete (very hard) - I think you'll have to do some shortcuts here, and not necessarily find the minimal set of edges, but do it in reasonable time.
2. Brake the graph into layers, there are many optimizations that can be done here, but I suggest you to keep it simple. iterate over all the graph's vertexes and each time collect all the vertexes with no incoming edges to a layer. This might produce a line-like graph in some simple cases, but it suits quite well in the case of UML graphs.
3. A good graph is one that has the smallest number of edges [crossing each other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_%28graph_theory%29), It doesn't sound important but this fact contributes greatly to the overall look of the graph. what determines the number of crossings is the order of arrangement of the edges in every layer.But again, finding the minimum number of crossings or finding a maximum crossing-free set of edges is NP-complete :( "so again it is typical to resort to heuristics, such as placing each vertex at a position determined by finding the average or median of the positions of its neighbors on the previous level and then swapping adjacent pairs as long as that improves the number of crossings."
4. The edges removed (or reversed) in the first step of the algorithm are returned to their original position.

And there you have it! a nice layered graph for your UML.

- If my explanation wasn't clear enough try and read the Wikipedia article on [Layered graph drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing) again, or ask me any questions, and I'll try to respond.
- Remember that this is an algorithm for the general case, and lots optimizations can be made to better handle your specific case.
- If you want more ideas for features for your UML tool, look at the wonderful work done by Jetbrains for their [IntelliJ UML tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/training/demos/uml-class-diagrams.html)

Hope that my comments here are helpful in any way.

**Important Update:**
since you stated that you are "*Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.*"
I attach **[This](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/TSE93.pdf)**
The formal documentation from graphviz (of dot's algorithm) that "describe a four-pass algorithm for drawing directed graphs. The ﬁrst pass ﬁnds an optimal rank assignment using a network simplex algorithm. The second pass sets the vertex order within ranks by an iterative heuristic incorporating a novel weight function and local transpositions to reduce crossings. The third pass ﬁnds optimal coordinates for nodes by constructing and ranking an auxiliary graph. The fourth pass makes splines to draw edges. The algorithm makes good drawings and runs fast."
http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/TSE93.pdf

Comment: +1 for the underlying graph theory behind this problem. Most robust graph layout generators will provide a topologically-sorted view of the data with layering, especially in cases where the graph is guaranteed to be acyclic or has rules to prune simple loops (for example, UML, org charts, and many other hierarchical organizations of the data in graph space). This addresses the algorithm component of this question very well, though I'm openly curious if one of the canned solutions will better meet their needs. :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You are right of course, It will take a lot of effort to impalement a satisfying solution by yourself, and the only upside is, that the result will be easier to control and customize.  If that single upside is worth the effort... that is for the reader to decide :). The reason I posted the this lengthy answer is that @javo stated that he "want to know algorithm of dot program" so  that will give him some basic understanding of the mechanics of the algorithm.

Comment: Agreed! And this is inherently very useful to me as well, because it presents a good design overview for the space. Thank you for posting it here. :)

Answer (score 3):

Constrained layout of connected components is a non-trivial problem that you might be better off using existing tools to solve.  You mentioned [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), but I don't think that you'll find a straightforward algorithm to port to Python.  A better solution might be to use [pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/) to interface with Graphviz and let it handle layout.

The flow would look something like:

1. Generate data for UML diagram
2. Convert to dot language using pydot
3. Layout using Graphviz tools, outputting dot language including layout
4. Parse the outputted layout with pydot
5. Display using Python

Graphviz handles the layout, but all the display is still within Python to allow whatever custom behavior you want to support.

Answer (score 2):

Providing my own answer [building on blahdiblah's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10094618/517815), you can indeed use the suggested workflow to generate your UML diagrams successfully.

But, this seems like it takes the garden path to your solution, which doesn't seem to be desirable to the design of your application. Specifically, we want to [*reduce the number of theoretical moving parts required*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_parts#Mechanical_efficiency_and_wear) to get this working.

Instead of using [pyreverse](http://www.logilab.org/2560), I recommend looking into [the alternatives mentioned in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260165/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-a-uml-diagram-from-python-source-code). Specifically, a tool such as [Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) may meet your needs better, both for the reduction in dependencies and in its ([MIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)) licensing structure.

Regardless of which path you choose, best of luck with your application.

Answer (score 0):

i m not a python programmer but functionally i can suggest you something.

1. You must have the count of the lines you will be having with each class
2. Keep the level number of the class that will help you to organize the classes on the basis of the level no.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show classes in an ordered manner (parents top, children bottom) you should keep a track of the "weight" of each class. What I mean by weight is the number of "parents".

For example, if B inherits from A, B.weight = 1 and A.weight = 0. And if C inherits from B, C.weight = 2. If you represent this as a line, class A will be printed on line 0, B on line 1 and C on line 2. Generally speaking, all classes of the same "weight" would be printed on the same virtual line.

Of course that's just the base idea, positioning element will be more diffcult than this if you want tu support complex objects (multi-heritance, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You are unlikely to get good results from real projects that weren't developed UML-first. That is a lesson we learned some 10 years ago using the first java-uml round-trip tools (TogetherJ). In text mode it is much too easy to get away with code that is impossible to draw nicely. The dynamic browser-based views of a smalltalk system are much more effective as a way to get insight in the code than UML tools can currently provide.

For the layout, just take a look at all the work done in CAD for electronics, especially printed circuit boards (PCBs). There are good placing and routing algorithms there. One of the things I've not seen an automated UML tool do right is handling a lot of subclasses, where you want layout to change from a single line of classes below the parent to a double line with the low nodes shifted half a node.