# Is there any tool to visualize relations between different Python objects within a package?

Tags: python, class, graph-visualization

While learning a new Python package it takes a great deal of time to learn about Python objects which makes the package. For example, in Pandas library, there is a method called to_html. It is a method of a class DataFrame, and DataFrame subclasses from a class NDFrame which resides in a module generic.py, etc...

I wonder if there is any tool which would visualize different relations between Python objects, for example inheritance.

I'm looking for a tool where you would type a Python method(with the class it belongs to), and the tool would visualize the relations - (which classes the class inherits from, or which other modules it uses).

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260165/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-a-uml-diagram-from-python-source-code

Comment: @AlexanderZhukov `Take a lood` - brilliant, combining `good` and `look` :))