# How can I use pyreverse in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pylint

I've installed Eclipse (latest stable) and integrated PyDev and PyLint succesfully. Now being a python noob I wonder if I could somehow get an UML
sheme from within Eclipse to do some reverse engineering of existing python code.

Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: Please see this duplicate, off-topic question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260165/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-a-uml-diagram-from-python-source-code

Comment: Hi @Barret I looked at that thread before and in context of my question I tried PyUML which seemed the most Eclipse solution. But this program is outdated and no longer active, not working... I came here to ask for an alternative specific Eclipse solution. So I don't see why this question is a duplicate (and off-topic). Please argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of Eclipse + PyDev UML plugin I will try to create a basic plugin/custom command. (PyUML is both not active and working..)

Starting from here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html 
and here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsAdvanced/article.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that pylint includes a way to get at the pyreverse features from within eclipse. You can try getting the UML outside Eclipse, or another plugin like http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-pyuml/

Comment: Don't try PyUML, installation problems unless you are willing to install an older Eclipse version (and perhaps older Python version).

http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipse-pyuml/discussion/?source=navbar