# Python- How to auto-generate UML diagrams from python code

Tags: python, eclipse-plugin, uml, pydev, eclipse-neon

Is there any **plugin for generating UML diagrams from python code.**
I found one- **pyUML**. I have downloaded it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-pyuml/), but how to install it to get it working with eclipse. And except this, are there any other options(plugins) which can generate UML diagrams from python code in eclipse?

Basically, I am interested in **auto-generating UML diagrams from my python** code. If its not possible with eclipse,then what are other possible options?

**EDIT:** I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886543/how-can-i-use-pyreverse-in-eclipse).

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can ask on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could you adapt the acceleo generator for Java, Java is not so far from Python.