# How can I represent a Python dictionary in UML?

Tags: python, uml

I would like to know how I can represent a Python dictionary using UML. This dictionary is an attribute of a class called Digraph. The keys are of type Node, and the values are of type Edge.

Comment: Duplicate of [What's the best way to generate a UML diagram from Python source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260165/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-a-uml-diagram-from-python-source-code) - Use the answers to simply populate the UML diagrams from your dictionary data.

Comment: @Torxed I disagree - this question has very little to do with Python and can be generally applied to any language (and their map/dictionary/hash/whatever)

Comment: @peter Then this question should maybe not be tagged with Python. This could have been both asked and responded without the need of even mentioning the language itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qualified associations are useful for modeling maps/dictionaries.

See [uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/property.html#qualifier) for some examples.

You can also read the official [UML (2.5) specs](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/) (see page 215)

And your particular problem can be represented as:

[image]

However note that this is only for nodes with single outgoing edges (its one-to-one mapping); if this wasn't your intention than the mapping would have to be Node to array of Edges. (and changing `1` into `*`).

Comment: Though the official UML documentation has improved it's still not really usable for every-day-users of UML. Stay with uml-diagrams.org.