# How can I add a simple generic type annotation for a dictionary in UML?

Tags: uml

In a UML class diagram, the value of one of the attributes of a class is a (typed) dictionary.  What is a proper UML type annotation? (Within the box; *not* as an association.)

For example, in Python I would annotate this attribute with `Dict[A,B]` or possibly `Mapping[A,B]`. I am not asking about Python; this is just one example of a somewhat generic attribute annotation.  I am open to the possibility that UML does not offer a language agnostic equivalent to this, but I am hoping that is not true.

Comment: I am asking about generic attribute annotation, directly with the class box. I do not wish to add a separate class box for `Dict` to the diagram. Therefore this is not a duplicate of [How can I represent a Python dictionary in UML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912096/how-can-i-represent-a-python-dictionary-in-uml)

Comment: @qwerty_so Python supports [type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) since version 3.5.

Comment: Uh, strange things happen :-/ Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In UML *Dict* is typically model as a *template class* with two *template parameters* for instance named *key* and *value*.

Let's say you want the class *C* has the attribute *a* being a `Dict[A,B]`, so you have a *binding* having the *template param substitutions* `key -> A` and `value -> B`.

There are several ways to show that in a *class diagram*.

For instance using the class *DictAB* to model `Dict[A,B]` :

[image]

or if you prefer :

[image]

But it is also possible to not use the auxiliary class *DictAB* and to use the textual representation of the *binding expression* (see [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) § 7.3.4 page 26) :

[image]

Comment: The very last example is what I am looking for. Is such an example in the UML docs? (As an aside, I guess I am really wishing UML directly supported a few ADTs.) Thanks.

Comment: @Alan  sorry I missed to put the reference to the norm, I edited my anwser to add : [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) § 7.3.4 page 26

Comment: @Alan It seems also the name of the template parameters in `typing.Dict` are *KT* and *KV*, but the way to do is the same of course