# What library or framework can be used to parse Python file and extract base classes as well as methods inside them

Tags: python-3.x, python-jedi

```
class A:
    def m1():
        // in a.m1
        pass
class B(A):
    def m2():
        // in b.m2
```

Parsing above code shall give me following info -
class names - B, base -> A, method names -> a.m1, b.m2

I have looked into [Jedi](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/api.html), but I don't see any Api to extract above information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to generate a UML diagram from Python source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260165/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-a-uml-diagram-from-python-source-code)

Comment: What do you want to do? If you just want to parse code, you could probably use https://github.com/davidhalter/parso/ or any other Python parser. Jedi is using Parso internally to do that. If you only deal with syntactically valid code, you can use the `ast` module in the `stdlib` as well.

Comment: Yes David, something like Parso or Jedi which has api to get base class information as well. Unfortunately, I could find any Api inside Jedi that is able to parse base class or if there's a different way to do it, I would like to know. What I mean is that information about class B using Jedi has no information about class A.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the standard library `pyclbr` module useful to determine classes, methods, and parent classes in a module. [here's its docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pyclbr.html)

Its `_main` function should help with some example usage and help get you to a solution (Running `python3 -m inspect pyclbr` will  show you the source code of the `pyclbr` module so you can see `_main`).

Here's the output of the `_main` function being run against `pyclbr` itself:

```
$ python3 -m pyclbr pyclbr
class _Object [] 53
  def __init__ 55
class Function [<__main__.Class object at 0x1047e56d0>] 68
  def __init__ 70
class Class [<__main__.Class object at 0x1047e56d0>] 78
  def __init__ 80
def _nest_function 89
def _nest_class 94
def readmodule 100
def readmodule_ex 112
def _readmodule 122
class _ModuleBrowser [<__main__.Class object at 0x1047e6410>] 186
  def __init__ 187
  def visit_ClassDef 195
  def visit_FunctionDef 220
  def visit_AsyncFunctionDef 230
  def visit_Import 233
  def visit_ImportFrom 248
def _create_tree 269
def _main 275
```

You'll probably need to access the `super` attributes of the Class and `readmodule_ex` returns to determine the base class info you want to output.

Pros:

- doesn't actually execute the module code the way `inspect` requires one to (so, in theory, you're safer running it against code you don't trust)
- quite fast

Cons:

- sometimes reports classes / functions from imported modules.  (For my purposes this hasn't mattered)