# suggestions for code map tools (python project)

Tags: python, static-code-analysis

are there tools to generate code maps of python project?

(basically, I would like to see all internal dependencies of functions and classes)

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to generate a UML diagram from Python source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260165/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-a-uml-diagram-from-python-source-code)

Comment: so, epydoc has issues indeed with python3; pylint / pyreverse seems working, although I am not super satisfied with results -- keep testing